# A triangle has sides $3x+1$, $x+2$, $x+3$ and an angle with a known cosine; find $x$ and area

Tags: trigonometry

[image]

I'm having trouble with Question 10. I have figured out $x$, which is $2$. I'm not sure how I can find the area of the triangle. Please look at the attachment above.

Comment: What did you try? Do you have some formulas for finding the areas of triangles?

Answer (score 6):

**HINT**

By law of cosine we have

$$c^2 = a^2 + b^2-2ab\cos \theta$$

then we can find the area by

$$A=\frac12 ab\sin \theta$$

Comment: Yeah, that's probably easier than Heron.

Comment: @BenW Yes indeed I think that the idea and the spirit for the homework is that. But Heron is always good invoke :)

Comment: @gimusi It's interesting that we get two solutions: one with $x = -\frac{12}{11}$ and one with $x=2$.

Comment: @TobyMak I didn't check that. I'll take a look.

Comment: @TobyMak Sorry, I didn't see that clearly but of course we need to esclude -12/11 therefore x=2 is the good one!

Answer (score 5):

If you have $x$, then you have all three side lengths.  Now just apply Heron's formula.

Comment: Thank you! This is definitely helpful if I don't have a calculator!

Comment: @Joshuap88 You would still need to find $x$ using a calculator.

Comment: @TobyMak $x$ can by surely found easily by hands from the quadratic equation obtined by the law of cosine.

Comment: @BenW With your method how would you use the law of cosine?

Comment: Didn't you use the law of cosines to find $x$?  Now you no longer need it.  Whether you use Heron's formula or $A=\frac{1}{2}ab\sin\theta$, you are done with LoC.

Comment: @BenW Ah ok sorry! You mean to use that only for the second part, now it is clear! Bye